# Is there a way to switch of the possibility to edit code while debugging but NOT in break mode

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 developing C#.NET I'm able to edit code while debugging even if not in break mode. With earlier versions I used to get the message 'Changes are not allowed while code is running'. Now I can start to write but the code is wavy underlined and I'm not able continue without stopping and recompiling.

I tried to disable Tools->Options->Debugging->General->Enable Edit and Continue but that has no effect. I find this behaviour very annoying.

Hoping for a hint to get it to work like it used to.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from Microsoft. May it help someone else too. :-)

In VS 2019 we allowed you to edit files even when the application being debugged is running. This wasn’t possible before as you have observed. These edits can’t be applied until after the application transitions to a break mode (e.g. a breakpoint is hit, or “Break All” command is issued). That’s why a squiggle is displayed on the changed text span to notify you about the fact that the change hasn’t been applied yet. Once the application transitions to a break mode these squiggles should disappear. If the changes are allowed to be made they will be applied once you resume the execution of the application (“Continue”, or “Step” commands are issued). It is not necessary to stop debugging and recompile, unless the changes made are “rude”. In that case the squiggles appear again and will inform you why the particular change can’t be applied.